# keep content of my comment when i want edit him

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have comments for my gossips and i display them in the show of my gossips.

When I clic on edit for my gossip that open new windows and that display me the actual title and content.

But when I clic on edit for my comment that open the view for edit bur the content is blank. How display the actual content when i want edit him.

**View - edit comment :**

```
<%= form_for edit_gossip_comment_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group new-gossip-field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group margin-left-50">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit Comment</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**View - edit gossip :**

```
<%= form_for @gossip do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group new-gossip-field">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group new-gossip-field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group margin-left-50">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit Gossip</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If i try to let @comment instead edit_gossip_comment_path that would not work, I dont really understand why.

If you need see more code tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your form of edit comment, you are not passing the comment, so you should pass the object of work for the form, like:

**View - edit comment :**

```
 <%= form_for @comment, url: edit_gossip_comment_path(@comment) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group new-gossip-field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group margin-left-50">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit Comment</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

with that, i belieave that the content of your comment will be show in the form.